# Is there a simple way to clone a glue job, but change the database connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a large number of clients who supply data in the same format, and need them loading into identical tables in different databases. I have set up a job for them in Glue, but now I have to do the same thing another 20 times

Is there any way I can take an existing job and copy it, but with changes to  the S3 filepath and the JDBC connection?

I haven't been able to find much online regarding scripting in AWS Glue. Would this be achievable through the AWS command line interface?

Answer (score 3):

The quickest way would be to use the aws cli.

```
aws glue get-job --job-name <value>
```

where value is the specific job that you are trying to replicate. You can then alter the s3 path and JDBC connection info in the JSON that the above command returns. Also, you'll need to give it a new unique name. Once you've done that, you can pass that in to:

```
aws glue create-job --cli-input-json <value>
```

where value is the updated JSON that you are trying to create a new job from.

See [AWS command line reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/index.html) for more info on the glue command line

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. Thank you very much :)

Comment: The CLI is awesome. I've pretty much automated the whole process end to end in a day. Thanks again for the advice

Answer (score 3):

use the command

```
aws glue create-job --generate-cli-skeleton
```

to generate the skeleton JSON

Use the below command to get the existing job's definition

> `aws glue get-job --job-name <value>`

Copy the values from the output of existing job's definition into skeleton

Remove the newline character and pass it as input to below command

```
aws glue create-job --cli-input-json <framed_JSON>
```

Here is the complete reference for Create Job AWS CLI documentation

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-job.html

PS: don't change the order of the elements in JSON (generated in skeleton), only update the connection and name

--cli-input-json (string) Performs service operation based on the JSON string provided. The JSON string follows the format provided by --generate-cli-skeleton. If other arguments are provided on the command line, the CLI values will override the JSON-provided values. It is not possible to pass arbitrary binary values using a JSON-provided value as the string will be taken literally.

--generate-cli-skeleton (string) Prints a JSON skeleton to standard output without sending an API request. If provided with no value or the value input, prints a sample input JSON that can be used as an argument for --cli-input-json. If provided with the value output, it validates the command inputs and returns a sample output JSON for that command.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the great answers here, you already know that the AWS CLI comes to the rescue.

> ***Tip***: if you don't want to install or update the AWS CLI, just use the [AWS CloudShell](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudshell/)!

I've tested the commands here using version:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/1.19.14 Python/3.8.5 Linux/5.4.0-65-generic botocore/1.20.14
```

If you want to create a new job from scratch, you'll want a template first, which you can get with:

```
aws glue create-job --generate-cli-skeleton > job_template.json
```

Then use your favourite editor (I like *vim*) to fill out the details in *job_template.json* (or whatever you call it).

But if DuckDuckGo or other engine sent you here, there's probably an existing job that you would like to clone and tweak. We'll call it "perfect_job" in this guide.

Let's get a list of all the jobs, just to check we're in the right place.

```
aws glue list-jobs --region us-east-1
```

The output shows us two jobs:

```
{
    "JobNames": [
        "perfect_job",
        "sunshine"
    ]
}
```

View our job:

```
aws glue get-job --job-name perfect_job --region us-east-1
```

The JSON output looks right, let's put it in a file so we can edit it:

```
aws glue get-job --job-name perfect_job --region us-east-1 > perfect_job.json
```

Let's `cp` that to a new file, say  `super_perfect_job.json`. Now you can edit it to change the fields as desired. The first thing of course is to change the Name!

Two things to note:

1. Remove the outer level of the JSON, we need the *value* of `Job` not the `Job` identifier itself. If you look at `job_template.json` created above, you'll see that it must start with `Name`, so it's a small edit to match the format requirement.
2. There's no `CreatedOn` or `LastModifiedOn` in `job_template.json` either, so let's delete those lines too. Don't worry, if you forget to delete them, the creation will fail with a helpful message like *'Parameter validation failed: Unknown parameter in input: "LastModifiedOn"'*.

Now we're ready to create the job! The following example will add Glue job "super_perfect_job" in the Cape Town region:

```
aws glue create-job --cli-input-json file://super_perfect_job.json --region af-south-1
```

But that didn't work:

> An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateJob
> operation: Please set only Allocated Capacity or Max Capacity.

I delete `MaxCapacity` and try again. Still not happy:

> An error occurred (InvalidInputException) when calling the CreateJob
> operation: Please do not set Allocated Capacity if using Worker Type
> and Number of Workers.

Fine. I delete `AllocatedCapacity` and have another go. This time the output is:

```
{
    "Name": "super_perfect_job"
}
```

Which means, success! You can confirm by running `list-jobs` again. It's even more rewarding to open the AWS Console and see it pop up in the web UI.

We can't wait to run this job, so we'll use the CLI as well, and we'll pass three additional parameters: `--fruit`, `--vegetable` and `--nut` which our script expects. But `--` would confuse the AWS CLI so let's store these in a file called `args.json` containing:

```
{
  "--fruit": "tomato",
  "--vegetable": "cucumber",
  "--nut": "almond"
}
```

And call our job like so:

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name super_perfect_job --arguments file://args.json --region af-south-1
```

Or like this:

```
aws glue start-job-run --job-name super_perfect_job --arguments '{"--fruit": "tomato","--vegetable": "cucumber"}'
```

And you can view the status of job runs with:

```
aws glue get-job-runs --job-name super_perfect_job --region us-east-1
```

As you can see, the AWS Glue API accessed by the AWS CLI is pretty powerful, being not only convenient, but allowing automation in Continuous Integration (CI) servers like Jenkins, for example. Run `aws glue help` for more commands and quick help or see the [online documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/index.html#cli-aws-glue) for more details.

For creating or managing permanent infrastructure, it's preferable to use Infrastructure as Code tools, such as CloudFormation or Terraform.